# Is it possible to increment integers/genvar inside a generate for loop

Tags: verilog

I've read elsewhere that this syntax `j = j + 1` is not allowed, but is it possible at all to increment variables outside the loop expression of the for loop?

Here is what I originally wanted to do. I wasn't sure how to go about making this generate statement, so i was thinking, I want to generate modules with parameters `20, 21, 22, 23, 25, 28, 29, 31` while using values from a 2d parameter array that is indexed using `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7`. So i thought, I would just make one for loop and then have a second variable `j` that starts at `0` and goes to `7`. Can I do that? If not, what is recommended?

```
genvar i; 
  integer j = 0;
  generate
    for (i = 20; i <= 31; i = i + 1) begin : NUM_OF_FF
      if (i != 21 && i != 24 && i != 26 && i != 27 && i != 30) begin
          lfsr
            #(
              .num_of_ff(i),
              .poly(lsfr_taps[j])
            )
          random_data_gen_lsfr
          (
            .clk(sys_clk),
            .rst(rst), 
            .out(lsfr_bits[i])
          );
          j = j + 1;
      end
    end
  endgenerate
```

Comment: Robert's answer below is how I would do it too. But regarding your code, why not define j as genvar? In that case I don't see why you can't increment it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an array of integer parameter (perhaps lsfr_taps in your example is something similar?)

```
module lfsr#(int num_of_ff=1, int poly=1)();
   initial $display("%m: %0d %0d", num_of_ff, poly);
endmodule

module simple;
   parameter int index_list_size = 8;
   parameter int index_list[index_list_size] = {20, 21, 22, 23, 25, 28, 29, 31};

   for (genvar i=0; i<index_list_size; ++i) begin: NUM_OF_FF
      lfsr#(.num_of_ff(i), .poly(index_list[i])) random_data_gen_lsfr();
   end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than try to increment the second variable (j) in the inner loop, you can use a constant function, and convert the poly parameter to an input:

```
function [7:0] tap_number;
  input [31:0] polynomial;
  input [7:0]  max_valid;
  integer i;
  begin
    tap_number = 0;
    for (i=0; i<max_valid; i=i+1)
      begin
        if (polynomial[i])
          tap_number = tap_number + 1;
      end
  end
endfunction

wire [7:0] lfsr_taps;
assign lfsr_taps = tap_number (poly, i);
     lfsr
        #(
          .num_of_ff(i),
        )
      random_data_gen_lsfr
      (
        .poly(lsfr_taps[j])
        .clk(sys_clk),
        .rst(rst), 
        .out(lsfr_bits[i])
      );
```